# remove number input arrows from specific input

Tags: css

I have a number input where I want to remove the increase/decrease buttons. This is done using:

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

However how do I write CSS to apply these to a specific input with id `myid` ?

```
<input type="number" id="myid">
```

Comment: You can add the id after the element's name with `#` like this: `input#myid::-webkit-outer-spin-button`.

Comment: thanks what about webkit-inner-spin-button ? can you post a complete answer ?

Comment: Just posted the comment and snippet in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the id after the element's name with `#` like below:

```css
input#myid::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input#myid::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input#myid[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myid">
```

Same goes whenever you want to target a specific element with a specific **class**. In this case, you will have to use `.` followed by the class name, e.g.

For the element below:

```
<input type="number" class="myclass">
```

The CSS selector should be formed like this:

```
input.myclass::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input.myclass::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input.myclass[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```